# What is wrong with my Visual Studio Login Prompt?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

This has only arisen since I've started developing - in VS 2103 Update 4 - for three different MS cloud accounts. When I open the Publish wizard to deploy an MVC 4 web app to an Azure web site, the VS login prompt keeps interfering i.e. blocking me. Despite entering the correct password, it keeps reappearing. Ad nausea. When I use Alt-F4 to close the login window, the publish is successful. This is more an annoyance than a show stopper, but it is hugely annoying, and disconcerting.

Comment: Have the same problem with my five accounts. When opening Server Explorer or publishing a site to Azure I have to provide the credentials for all subscription registered with Visual Studio. It is really annoying. Best way would to open a request on [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) (if there is no issue similar to this one yet).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://kapiltak.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-create-virtual-application-in.html): Remember that most of the available operations can be used through the azure service management [rest services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx)